# Ajax onreadystatechange function with readystate=4 and status=200 called many times

Tags: javascript, ajax

Sometimes i can see alert("Here") coming multiple times and even it's not exiting from if block.

```
    AJAX                    = createXMLHttpRequest();
    AJAX.onreadystatechange = handler;
    AJAX.open("GET", myurl , true);

    function handler()
    {
       if(AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200)
       {
         alert("Here");
       }
    }
```

lease help me to get out ot this. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how many times is the `handler` function called ?

Comment: around 20+ times and actually i have my code inside that block it's not executing

Comment: i have added 2 alerts before & after my code and showing processing image too. i can not see second alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution for my problem. When i made async flag is to false then it's working fine, then only i can see alert only one time.

```
 AJAX.open("GET", myurl , false);
```